# Custom order for an activerecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I cannot solve an issue in my views.

I have to show on a page a collection of contents from my `Content` class.
My `Content` class has some subclass that define the type of content: "News", "Reviews", "Video" etc.

In my view I need to render a list of content with a custom order:

```
news
news
news
news
content of any other type
news
news
news
news
content of any other type
...
```

Basically I need to show every 4 news a content that is not a news.

At this moment in my controller I have

```
all_contents = @special_page.contents
@news = all_contents.select { |c| c.type == 'News' }
@contents = all_contents - @news
```

@contents is an array of objects with every content that is not a news and with some tricks in the view (using index in enumarator) I'm able to obtain what I need.

But then I realize that I have an issue: I have Kaminari for pagination and when I request the next page I cannot use this system for the second page.

So I need get a collection of contents already ordered, and I cannot understand how.

Comment: Do you have 1 pagination element or each block of news have the similar element?

Comment: Every element has the same attributes but I have different partials for news and other contents so I need to render a partial for the news and another partial for other types

Comment: If you need to paginate the results you need to do the ordering in the database. Just selecting the contents in a custom order based on the type can be done by using order together with a case statement. `ORDER BY case contents.type WHEN 'news' THEN 1 ...`. However the requirement that you need to do something else on every 4th row requires that you use something like a window function (`RANK OVER ...`). I'm not 100% sure how to solve it but you'll most likely want to setup one scope to get everying in the order you want and use it in the FROM clause.

Comment: `content = Content.from(Content.my_custom_order, :contents).paginate(...)`. The best approach is going to depend very much on what RDBMS you are using. My best advice is to rephrase the question from a Rails question to a SQL question. Add good examples of the tables, data and expected result and tag the question with your RDBMS (postgres, mysql) etc. Those tags have followers that are much more skilled at SQL then the average Rails dev.

Comment: Actually rendering the records is going to be the easy part. "Rails determines the name of the partial to use by looking at the model name in the collection. In fact, you can even create a heterogeneous collection and render it this way, and Rails will choose the proper partial for each member of the collection" https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections

Answer (score -2):

Probably just paginate "news" and put some logic in view (or even in controller),

```
@news.each_with_index do |item, index|
  if index % 4 == 0
     = render 'some_other_item'
  end
  = render 'post', post: item
end
```

I think you understand the idea

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. But when I call the second page I lose the contents... that's why I'm trying the get the collection already ordered

Comment: This won't actually fix anything. You can just pass `render collection: @news` and rails will automatically render the correct partial based on the class name. The issue is really more a SQL issue of ordering the records in the first place and no ruby loop is going to fix that problem in a scalable way.

Comment: @RobertoPezzali fundamentally you are saying "I have two different collections that I need to interleave in the view".  Have you considered treating them as different collections that are paginated with different sizes?  For example, if you want to show 25 items on a page, then paginate 'news' items with a page size of 20 and 'other' items with a page size of 5.  `@news = Content.where(type: 'news')` and `@contents = Content.where.not(type: 'news')` should help